# How to get custom slider in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get a custom slider in tkinter or another slider like this one

[slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F0iW.jpg)

The default tkinter slider isn't very good so how it can be changed ? (even the simplest way to do it)

I will appreciate if the thing is not done with a class because I did'nt put a single one in 300 lines of code and it will confuse me a bit, I won't mix class/not class, I'll just rewrite the code as a class with the self args but later

Here's a simple Slider in tkinter :

```
scale = Scale(root,from_=0,to=500,orient=HORIZONTAL)
```

How to make it customizable ?

A weird thing is that in some tutorials like this one https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-slider/

The tkinter slider are different from what I get or they're presented in a different way

Comment: I think you use `tkinter.Scale` and the one in the link is `tkinter.ttk.Scale`.

Comment: It change nothing in both cases

Comment: They are different in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.13.

Comment: I have Python3.8.13 but I'm not on Windows 7 :/ ...

Comment: If you want a better looking Slider or GUI, you can check out [customtkinter](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to use a more modernized scale widget using Tkinter's ttk library:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# tk basic Scale
scale1 = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=500, orient="horizontal")
scale1.pack()

# ttk modern Scale
scale2 = ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=500, orient="horizontal")
scale2.pack()
```

[Notice the differences between the two here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FfSv.png)

^ This is for macOS so it will look slightly different if you are on Windows.